# How to prevent "Shell Infrastructure Host" (sihost.exe) from slowing down the opening of images on the network?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11

We have a folder with 200,000 files on a network share. Customer won't allow us to separate the files into separate year folders which would solve the issue.

The issue is, when opening images from within this folder, it can take 2 or 3 minutes to actually load. If we load a PDF, it's instant. This happens even if you don't use file explorer, and instead use their CMS system which runs a shell command to open the file directly.

When the file is triggered to open, the Photos app opens, is blank white while it loads. While it loads, Task Manager shows "Shell Infrastructure Host" (sihost.exe) does something on the network at 10Mbps for the duration before the image loads.

The images are small, mostly around 100KB and the PDFS are the same. It's nothing to do with a bottleneck on the network.

Most people in the customers office have this issue, except a single PC which doesn't have the issue, there is nothing special about this PC.

What is "Shell Infrastructure Host" and is there a way we can disable this?

Comment: Have a look here esp at slideshow and accent color and compare it with the computer that doesn't have the problem.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/272930/what-is-windows-shell-experience-host-and-why-is-running-on-my-pc/

Comment: Thanks but this isn't the issue. It only happens with this specific folder and it doesn't have high CPU or memory usage, but does appear to be doing something over the network while it loads.

Comment: So you tested that their is no slideshow background and tested that automatically choose accent color is not set?

Answer (score 3):

this is what really helped me https://www.technewstoday.com/shell-infrastructure-host-high-cpu-usage/

for short term solution, kill sihost.exe (this brought back the Shell Infrastructure Host to normal CPU load without restarting)
maybe also kill explorer.exe.

as you don't have the CPU load issue, maybe it is still a photo-viewer problem. so maybe change the viewer to a less buggy one than the microsoft one

Comment: Thanks, we did eventually move old files to another folder which prevented the issue, however the client has filled up the folder again, and the problem is coming back. I will try another photo viewer as I recall it may not have happened when we used mspaint during a test. Crazy that the software doesn't automatically put the images into folders, but have been told our client uses the CMS much more than any of their other customers.